# add elements in scala lists

Tags: scala, list

I am still learning Scala and I am facing the following issue. Currently I have the following list in input

```
val listA=List("banana,africa,1,0",
"apple,europe,1,2",
"peas,africa,1,4")
```

The wanted output is :

```
val listB=list("banana,africa,1,0,1",
"apple,europe,1,2,3",
"peas,africa,1,4,5")
```

My aim is to add an element corresponding to the sum of the two last elements for each line in the list. I wrote the following basic function

```
 def addSum(listin:List[String]):List[String]= {
  listin.map(_.split(",")).map(d => d + "," + d(2)+d(3))

}
```

this is not working any suggestion aboit a better way to do it please

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution is to do something like below

```
listA.map(str => str.split(",")).map(arr => (arr ++ Array(arr(2).toInt+arr(3).toInt)).mkString(","))
```