# change a list column order scala

Tags: scala

I have the following list and I want to change the order of columns

```
val list=List("banana,QS,1,0,0",
"apple,EE,1,2,1", 
"peas,US,1,4,4")
```

The expected result is:

```
val list=List("banana,QS,0,1,0",
"apple,EE,1,1,2", 
"peas,US,4,1,4")
```

Best Regards

Comment: first of all you are asking to do your assignment and also not being specific which columns to change. your example does not have consistent pattern

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add elements in scala lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50508034/add-elements-in-scala-lists) (duplicate question by a duplicate user)

Comment: @scalacode; In the past 5 days you've asked 5 questions and gotten 9 reasonable answers, but none of them have been acceptable to you (i.e. none have been marked as the "accepted" answer). If you don't like the answers you get here on SO why do you keep coming back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are looking for swapping column 3rd with 4th,

- split with `,`
- construct new List with swapped columns
- concat List to get string

example,

```
scala> val list = List("banana,QS,1,0,0", "apple,EE,1,2,1", "peas,US,1,4,4")
list: List[String] = List(banana,QS,1,0,0, apple,EE,1,2,1, peas,US,1,4,4)

scala> list.map(_.split(",")).map(elem => List(elem(0), elem(1), elem(3), elem(2), elem(4)).mkString(","))
res0: List[String] = List(banana,QS,0,1,0, apple,EE,2,1,1, peas,US,4,1,4)
```